# Access native slider bar control?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

What form control can I use that is native in Access 2007+ that can be self-contained (not require Active-X) to dynamically display graphically the ratio of attribute, where I can:

1. Set its initial value through VBA upon load;
2. Read the result back into my code?

**Background:**

Client asked me to create a sales tool for use on the various laptops of his various salesmen, all of whom use some version of MS-Access. I don't have any control over the environment the tool will be used in. Client likes and wants Access to be the medium, but doesn't know or care what the tables are, he just wants forms.

One aspect of his sales tool is a way for the salesman to display to the customer the ratio of products with and without a certain attribute.

Say we are selling widgets, we figure out the size/weight/etc. widget we need, how many we need, but we also need to figure out how many of those widgets should have a certain picture on them.

Say we need 10 widgets, I need a way for the salesman to display and dynamically change how many widgets have the picture, and how many don't, and then read this information into things like the invoice and final price.

To me, it sounds like a slider bar (like the scroll bar on the side of your browser window), but I am open to options.

**Bonus:**

What is the command to create this control in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works in Access 2016, but I haven't been able to text it in 2007 yet. If anyone can do that for me so I can be sure, I would appreciate it.

To summarize, I basically stacked 2 different colored labels underneath an invisible label, and used click events.

```
Option Explicit

Sub createsliderform()

    Dim slidernum, newformname, thisFormName As String
    Dim controlnum, i As Integer
    Dim thisform As Form
    Dim startheight, lngReturn As Long

substart:

    slidernum = 0
    slidernum = InputBox("Please enter the number of sliders you would like, from 1 to 22. " & vbNewLine & "(Forms can only be so tall.)")
    If slidernum = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not isinteger(slidernum) Then MsgBox "Please enter only integers.": GoTo substart
    If slidernum > 22 Then MsgBox slidernum & " would make the form " & slidernum * 1440 & " twips tall, and Access 2016 only allows a form to be 31680 twips tall, maximum.": GoTo substart

    Dim myControls As Object
    Set myControls = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    myControls.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    controlnum = 0
    newformname = "sliderForm"

    Set thisform = CreateForm
    thisFormName = thisform.Name
    DoCmd.Close acForm, thisFormName, acSaveYes
    Set thisform = Nothing
    DoCmd.Rename newformname, acForm, thisFormName
    DoCmd.OpenForm newformname, acDesign
    Forms(newformname).Width = 6.5 * 1440
    Forms(newformname).Detail.Height = 0

    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 3, "Sub sliderbar(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single, thisform As String, thiscontrol As String, othercontrol As String, mytotalpossible As String)"
    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 4, "Dim totalpossible As Integer"
    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 5, "If isinteger(mytotalpossible) Then totalpossible = mytotalpossible Else totalpossible = 0"
    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 6, "If X > Forms(thisform).Controls(thiscontrol).Width Then X = Forms(thisform).Controls(thiscontrol).Width"
    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 7, "If X < 0 Then X = 0"
'I want to encourage all or nothing behavior giving the appearance of choice with the below. Obviously we could have it snap to location if we wanted.
    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 8, "Forms(thisform).Controls(othercontrol).Width = X"
    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 9, "Forms(thisform).Controls(thiscontrol).Caption = Round(totalpossible * Forms(thisform).Controls(othercontrol).Width / Forms(thisform).Controls(thiscontrol).Width) & "" of "" & totalpossible & "" widgets have pictures."""
    Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines 10, "End Sub"

    For i = 1 To slidernum

        startheight = Forms(newformname).Detail.Height
        Forms(newformname).Detail.Height = Forms(newformname).Detail.Height + 1440

        Set myControls(controlnum) = CreateControl(newformname, acTextBox, acDetail, , , 0.2 * 1440, 0.3 * 1440 + startheight, 1 * 1440, 0.2 * 1440)
        controlnum = controlnum + 1

        Set myControls(controlnum) = CreateControl(newformname, acLabel, acDetail, , , 0.2 * 1440, 0.7 * 1440 + startheight, 3 * 1440, 0.2 * 1440)
        With myControls(controlnum)
            .BackStyle = 1
            .BackColor = RGB(207, 123, 121)
            .SpecialEffect = 2
        End With
        controlnum = controlnum + 1

        Set myControls(controlnum) = CreateControl(newformname, acLabel, acDetail, , , 0.2 * 1440, 0.7 * 1440 + startheight, 1.5 * 1440, 0.2 * 1440)
        With myControls(controlnum)
            .BackStyle = 1
            .BackColor = RGB(34, 177, 76)
            .SpecialEffect = 1
        End With
        controlnum = controlnum + 1

        Set myControls(controlnum) = CreateControl(newformname, acLabel, acDetail, , , 0.2 * 1440, 0.7 * 1440 + startheight, 3 * 1440, 0.2 * 1440)
        With myControls(controlnum)
            .BackStyle = 0
            .ForeColor = vbBlack
            .TextAlign = 2
            .Caption = "Choose an integer for the number of widgets."
        End With

        lngReturn = Forms(newformname).Module.CreateEventProc("Mousemove", Forms(newformname).Controls(myControls(controlnum).Name).Name)
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 1, "if button=1 then"
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 2, "Me." & myControls(controlnum - 3).Name & ".setfocus"
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 3, "sliderbar Button, Shift, X, Y, Me.Name, Me." & myControls(controlnum).Name & ".Name, Me." & myControls(controlnum - 1).Name & ".Name, Me." & myControls(controlnum - 3).Name & ".text"
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 4, "end if"

        lngReturn = Forms(newformname).Module.CreateEventProc("mouseup", Forms(newformname).Controls(myControls(controlnum).Name).Name)
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 1, "Me." & myControls(controlnum - 3).Name & ".setfocus"
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 2, "sliderbar Button, Shift, X, Y, Me.Name, Me." & myControls(controlnum).Name & ".Name, Me." & myControls(controlnum - 1).Name & ".Name, Me." & myControls(controlnum - 3).Name & ".text"

        lngReturn = Forms(newformname).Module.CreateEventProc("Change", Forms(newformname).Controls(myControls(controlnum - 3).Name).Name)
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 1, "If Me." & myControls(controlnum - 3).Name & ".Text = """" Or Not isinteger(Me." & myControls(controlnum - 3).Name & ".Text) Then totalpossible = 0 Else totalpossible = Me." & myControls(controlnum - 3).Name & ".Text"
        Forms(newformname).Module.InsertLines lngReturn + 2, "Me." & myControls(controlnum).Name & ".Caption = Round(totalpossible * Me." & myControls(controlnum - 1).Name & ".Width / Me." & myControls(controlnum).Name & ".Width) & "" of "" & totalpossible & "" widgets have pictures."""

        controlnum = controlnum + 1

        Set myControls(controlnum) = CreateControl(newformname, acLabel, acDetail, , , 1.25 * 1440, 0.3 * 1440 + startheight, 3 * 1440, 0.2 * 1440)
        myControls(controlnum).Caption = "<-- Enter the total amount of widgets here."
        controlnum = controlnum + 1

    Next i

        DoCmd.Close acForm, newformname, acSaveYes
        DoCmd.OpenForm newformname, acNormal

End Sub

Public Function isinteger(testme) As Boolean
    Dim mytest As Integer
    isinteger = False
    If Len(testme) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    mytest = Int(testme)
    If Err.Number = 13 Then Exit Function
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Int(testme) - testme = 0 Then isinteger = True
End Function
```

If you are kind enough to test this in different environments for me, please put this in an empty module in an empty database, run it, look at the "sliderForm", and then try to break the form. You know... think like a salesman.

Comment: Not being an expert in graphics or user interface, the improvements that I wasn't sure how to create included greater visual contrast between raised and sunken, and a slider bar that isn't quite so monochromatic (has texture, as in slightly varying shades of color in the label background fill, which is likely impossible with labels). I know and discarded how to add a thumb or have it snap to place, for the purposes of this application.

Comment: Never mind the testing, he just bought new laptops for his whole sales force, and had them loaded with Office Professional 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps just place a text box and then allow the up/down arrow key to change the value. And also perhaps place a button above and below the control to up/down the value.

Say something like this:

[image]

And yes, as a general rule you likely want to avoid the slider control unless you have some installer to ensure that the slider will be installed on the target computer. However, perhaps in place of a slider, you cook up an interface like the above. (so two clicks on the +100 button would add 200 to the box).

Comment: this is good. Not exactly what I was hoping for, because being able to display a ratio would make a difference in this particular application. Now, don't get me wrong, I love the buttons (wasn't sure exactly how to implement spinner control in this environment, I like this), and I could easily add the total/max to the display somehow to show ratio... it just isn't as graphically direct as I was hoping. But maybe it isn't possible?

Comment: "...maybe [what I was hoping] isn't..."

Comment: Well, the above box could display some kind of ratio in place of a number like above. However, you can most certainly adopt the slider control, it only a question of ensuring that the ActiveX control is available on the target machine.

Comment: If those are the options, then I guess displaying it graphically isn't possible. I can't ensure anything about the target machines, and if even one of the salesmen don't have it installed, configured correctly, or who knows what, the tool will be suspect and I will have to jump through far too many hoops to get paid. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a slider control here.  In the OnChange event of the slider, set an invisible textbox equal to the value:

```
Private Sub MySlider_OnChange()
  Me.MyInvisibleTextbox.Text = MySlider.Value
End Sub
```

Then, use that textbox value in the WHERE clause of the query that drives the invoice.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Let's pretend I'm stupid (not unrealistic, I am a PM, not a DBA): Are you talking about the Active-X slider control? If so, don't we try to avoid Active-X controls when we don't have control over versioning and the environment? How do I make sure that salesmen (no need to pretend about expertise level here) have the correct environment for Active-X controls to work? Can I use late binding to solve this problem? Sorry, I am a bit of a neophyte in form controls.

Comment: In general, I do try to avoid ActiveX due to versioning issues.  I work in a large company (30,000+ employees) and that's a very real problem.  If your company is smaller, it may not be an issue so I offered it as a solution.